# Commenting on deleted answers, if you downvoted and can see them

Tags: feature-request

As downvoting encourages you to give feedback,
I feel like you should be able to comment on an answer or question if it just got deleted recently and you are still able to see it.

The reason why I think this is useful is because if you donwvote it's non-constructive and possibly temporary feedback and insecure users can be intimated by it. I just downvoted a right answer and wanted to tell the user to change 2 lines, because the style of the lines (lines with copied code which will lead to bugs in the long term when 1 is changed because the other doesn't automatically get changed as well).

He deleted the post immediately, probably thinking that he did some major fuck up, and I couldn't comment on it anymore.

OFC, you can easily avoid that, by commenting first and then downvoting (or not deleting answer before getting feedback), but IDK how many people on SE do this in general.

I don't think that implementing this would be super difficult, simply delaying the fade out of deleted answers you are typing a comment on and keeping the ability send comments to anything you see would solve this. (If it's harder than that probably not worth the time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well... quoting you (emphasis mine):

> ***I just downvoted a right answer*** and wanted to tell the user to change 2 lines

Why would you downvote a correct answer? If you think the answer was correct, but could be improved, you could comment first, give the OP time to make changes if they're willing to accept them, then use an upvote, no vote or downvote depending on the outcome.

---

As to the feature request aspect:

When a post is deleted - voting and commenting are disabled (diamond moderators are allowed to comment but that happens in rare circumstances and only to convey a one-way message to the user/additional context that 10k+ users can see).

Changing the rules to be "The OP" (because they might want to respond, right?) or anyone who has downvoted it would be a change in that logic and anyone aware of the rules you propose would be able to identify you as the downvoter.

If I decided to delete an answer (for whatever reason) - I'm not sure the idea of people being able to ping me in a non-peer observable way - and those users are known to have downvoted me - is in the least bit appealing and too open to abuse.

Comment: I mean, people downvote correct answers on sight for all sorts of reasons. At this point it's futile to argue against it even though, like you, I disagree with that practice.

Comment: I have to correct myself. I mean the answer was going into the right direction. The coding-style just made is significantly worse than other answers already given.

Comment: I'd actually want to see comments on deleted answers or even questions enabled for 10k users, as a means to interact on the reason why it's deleted/closed/irrelevant/too narrow etc.

Comment: @Shimmy you can see comments on deleted posts as long as the comments themselves aren't deleted.

Comment: @JonClements, I know but you can't add new ones.